# Should I fix my helpful but incorrect answer?

Tags: discussion, edits

I offered some [help](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32243102/sql-retrieve-inner-query-value/32243366#32243366) but I got my syntax wrong. However, this helped the questioner fix eir problem, who has commented about how e made it work, and accepted my answer.  So my answer is incorrect but you can reconstitute the correct solution by following the comments.

Should I go and fix the answer?

Comment: Yes, incorrect answers should be corrected

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your answer solved the problem with small issues notwithstanding, all the more you should fix it. Don't make readers go through the answer only to find that there was a small mistake somewhere that was addressed in the comments. All that does is waste their time.